/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (1442972264) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314)
I am using jemalloc jeprof to generate the pdf file, this is the command look like:
jeprof --show_bytes --pdf texhub-server texhub.out.1.7.i7.heap > profile.pdf

but the log shows error like this:
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (3221225545) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 575.
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (1768555783) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (184549714) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (1768555783) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (184549714) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (1768555783) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (184549714) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (4189390336) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (4280811833) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Offset (1576175623) greater than or equal to .debug_str size (50539314).
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 24396.
/usr/bin/addr2line: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 47096.

Am I missing some lib to install? what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the version info:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ dump]# jeprof -v
jeprof (part of jemalloc 5.2.1-0-gea6b3e973b477b8061e0076bb257dbd7f3faa756)
based on pprof (part of gperftools 2.0)

Copyright 1998-2007 Google Inc.

This is BSD licensed software; see the source for copying conditions
and license information.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

this is the Operation System info:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ dump]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111
Release:    8.5.2111
Codename:   n/a

this is the binutils verison info:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ ~]# yum install binutils
Last metadata expiration check: 3:14:41 ago on Sat 27 Jul 2024 02:50:20 PM CST.
Package binutils-2.30-108.el8_5.1.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!


This answer suggests the issue could be that the binutils in use is too old. Posting as a comment, and not an answer, as haven't verified the solution myself.
